# Load values in Multiple Selection screen in SAP

Tags: vbscript, sap-gui

Trying to automate a process using **SAP-Gui Scripting,** where in there is a need to paste multiple values in the multiple selection screen in SAP.

[image]

I will not be able to use, `paste from clipboard` as by the time this gets executed, the clipboard contents would get changed.  When I record `import from file` option, the command is not getting recorded.  Is there some way to achieve this?

```
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nfs10n"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_SO_BUKRS_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press

'  **The import from file command should go here.**

session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[24]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
```

I tried the `CopyText` command but it is not working as intended, though not sure why.

```
Copytext fromFile="myfile.txt" toText="t1"
Copytext fromText="t1" -toclipboard
```

Is there some way to achieve this?, ***like reading the file into clipboard before using paste from clipboard command***...  Currently there are around 3000 such line items and looping them through is making the script to run for long.

Answer (score 2):

If the selection "Show native Dialog boxes of Microsoft Windows" ist not active, then the script might look like this:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_S_RECNNR_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[23]").press
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = "z:\"
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = "test.txt"
session.findById("wnd[2]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 8
session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
```

Comment: Can you help me.. How do I turn it off ?  "Show native Dialog boxes of Microsoft Windows"

Comment: ALT/F12 for Local Layout Change => Options => Scripting Support => see above

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the issue is in the settings for SAP GUI Scripting. There should be disabled / deactivated all three options for selection. Especially "dialog box of Microsoft Windows shows". Then you can also record the button 23 and leave the button 24 off.

P.S. The "CopyText" command comes from GuiXT and can not be readily applied within a VB script.

Regards,
ScriptMan

Comment: I did the same, and I was able to record the Button23... However, I'm not able to provide the file name within the Windows Dialog box...  The macro just stalls there until the user click "Open" button.